# How and in which cases are setGroup() and setGroupSummary() methods in Notification class used

Tags: android, push-notification

Now I'm  using notificationID to update already visible notification with new one. I would really like to see practical example on how to use this two methods and how notification grouping looks like.

I'm using galaxy S3 with 4.3 and I think it should support this kind of rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These only affect the presentation of your notifications on an Android Wear device. If you set a group summary, and there's a paired Android Wear device available, only the group summary should be seen on the phone/tablet, and only the other ones in the group will appear on the Wear device (as "stacked notifications").

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Stacked) demonstrates the use of `setGroup()` and `setGroupSummary()`, though it will only really be useful if you are experimenting with Android Wear.

**UPDATE**: These also affect mobile devices running Android 7.1+, as well as Wear devices.

Comment: Great thx, saved me some time because I was trying update counter on pending notifications (bottom right corner in notification) using these methods. I suppose that I should persist info on how many times notification was updated, counting notifs with same id, in table and use it then? There is no method which can set this automatically?

Comment: @MunezNS: "I should persist info on how many times notification was updated, counting notifs with same id, in table and use it then?" -- I do not know what "it" is. If you are going to be using `setGroup()` and `setGroupSummary()`, you will need to have some idea of what outstanding notifications have not yet been handled by the user. That way you can set the group summary properly, plus switch away from stacked notifications if the stack gets too big. It cannot be done "automatically" simply because Android has no way to know if the user handled notifications by going straight to your UI.

Comment: By "it" I meant on counter which will count how many notifications with the same id have been build and shown so I can show number of pending notifications in the stack.